# MySQL join type for records in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, outer-join

The title is a little awkward, but I will do my best to explain what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have a table called `Users` and another called `Friends`.

The abstract structure of the `Users` table is:

```
+----+------+----------+----------+
| ID | Name | Username | Password |
+----+------+----------+----------+
```

The `Friends` table has an abstract structure like:

```
+----+--------+----------+--------+
| ID | UserID | FriendID | Hidden |
+----+--------+----------+--------+
```

Where the `UserID` is the ID of the user who sent the friend request and the `FriendID` is the recipient of the request. The hidden column will have a value of 1 if the recipient has chosen to hide the request.

I am wanting to compress this all down to one query, so far I have two separate ones which use either `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`.

To find sent requests and current friends:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE 
       WHEN C.ID IS Null THEN "Request Sent" 
       ELSE "Friends" 
    END AS Status 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         A.ID, A.Name, E.Hidden
     FROM
         Users A 
     INNER JOIN 
         Friends E ON A.ID = E.UserID
     WHERE
         A.ID in (SELECT UserID 
                  FROM Friends 
                  WHERE FriendID = "1" AND Deleted='No')) C
RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         B.ID, B.Name, F.Hidden
     FROM
         Users B 
     INNER JOIN 
         Friends F ON B.ID = F.FriendID
     WHERE
         B.ID in (SELECT FriendID 
                  FROM Friends 
                  WHERE UserID = "1" AND Deleted = 'No')) D ON C.ID = D.ID
```

As for friend requests received and current friends:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN D.ID IS Null THEN "Wants to be your friend" ELSE "Friends" END AS Status FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT
A.ID, A.Name, E.Hidden
FROM
Users A INNER JOIN Friends E ON A.ID=E.UserID
WHERE
A.ID in (SELECT UserID FROM Friends WHERE FriendID = "1" AND Deleted='No')) C
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT
B.ID, B.Name, F.Hidden
FROM
Users B INNER JOIN Friends F ON B.ID=F.FriendID
WHERE
B.ID in (SELECT FriendID FROM Friends WHERE UserID = "1" AND Deleted='No')) D
ON C.ID=D.ID
```

The venn diagram below may be a vital illustrative push if I haven't explained what I need.

[image: Venn Diagram]

Please note, for the purpose of constructing the querie(s) I have selected all columns, but I will only require the friends names and ID's at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `union all` or `union distinct` between the two queries this will return all the results in one table.

```
SELECT *, D.ID, CASE WHEN D.ID IS Null THEN "Wants to be your friend" ELSE "Friends" END AS Status FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT
A.ID, A.Name, E.Hidden
FROM
Users A INNER JOIN Friends E ON A.ID=E.UserID
WHERE
A.ID in (SELECT UserID FROM Friends WHERE FriendID = "1" AND Deleted='No')) C
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT
B.ID, B.Name, F.Hidden
FROM
Users B INNER JOIN Friends F ON B.ID=F.FriendID
WHERE
B.ID in (SELECT FriendID FROM Friends WHERE UserID = "1" AND Deleted='No')) D
ON C.ID=D.ID
union all
SELECT *, D.ID, CASE WHEN C.ID IS Null THEN "Request Sent" ELSE "Friends" END AS Status FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT
A.ID, A.Name, E.Hidden
FROM
Users A INNER JOIN Friends E ON A.ID=E.UserID
WHERE
A.ID in (SELECT UserID FROM Friends WHERE FriendID = "1" AND Deleted='No')) C
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT
B.ID, B.Name, F.Hidden
FROM
Users B INNER JOIN Friends F ON B.ID=F.FriendID
WHERE
B.ID in (SELECT FriendID FROM Friends WHERE UserID = "1" AND Deleted='No')) D
ON C.ID=D.ID
```

Comment: That appears to have worked after I change `UNION ALL` to `UNION DISTINCT` to stop repeating rows if two users were friends. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Just another extra bit, is it possible to provide the ID of the user, being 1 in this question, only once? It's just I have a session table too so I will be using an inner join statement to get the users ID from their session ID. It's alright if not though!

Comment: don't you already have a case structure dictating whether this is a 1 or not?

Comment: you can do that, add it from your sub-query to your main query before the case structure in both queries.

Comment: I'll give it a go, could you edit your answer just as a bit of a hint? I won't un-accept it if you don't want to

Comment: So wait what exactly do you want to see? 1? or the actual field value for D.ID? or A.ID? you have a lot of id's so your terminology is a bit ambiguous

Comment: Sorry, in my query there are two where clauses: `UserID = "1"` and `FriendID="1"`, this is the ID of the user who is wanting the data, so only data which is applicable to him/her should be returned. I suppose after all of the current query, I could just do something like `WHERE ID="1"`

Comment: Yes, add that to your main query.